# Javascript: присвоить input checked в зависимости от выбора радио кнопки

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Есть такой код, который я получил от сервера и вставил в тело страницы:

```
 <div id="browsers">
     <p><b>Браузер:</b><Br>
         <input type="radio" name="browser" value="ie"> Internet Explorer<Br>
         <input type="radio" name="browser" value="opera"> Opera<Br>
         <input type="radio" name="browser" value="firefox" checked="checked"> Firefox<Br>
     </p>
</div>
```

В поле с `value="firefox"` установлен параметр `checked`.

Как на JavaScript(без использования библиотек jQuery и подобных) можно при нажатии на другую радио кнопку переопределись этот параметр?

Например, при нажатии на `input` с `value="opera"`  для него устанавливался бы параметр `checked="checked"`, а с предыдущего, в данном случае у `value="firefox"` этот `checked="checked"` убирался. И так для всех радиокнопок.

Другими словами, каким образом можно сделать установку `checked` для радио кнопок динамическим в зависимости от нажатия на кнопку.

P.s. Слышал, что `checked`  по нажатию автоматически присваивает браузер. Но в моем случае хотелось бы явно установить, чтобы в консоле(во вкладке elements с исходным кодом) были видны изменения в html коде.
 Спасибо!

Comment: "чтобы в console.log были видны изменения в html коде." - они уже там есть.

Comment: @Igor прошу прощения, не совсем правильно выразился. Изменения в консоле  во вкладке Elements, где выводится исходный код страницы.

Comment: @Pavel как Вы уже и сказали это свойство устанавливает браузер и писать дополнительный код для принудительного обновления DOM, на мой взгляд, маразм.

Comment: @XelaNimed все ли браузеры присваивают? Может ли быть такое, что какой-нибудь мобильный браузер не умеет это делать? Поэтому для надежности хотелось бы установить вручную

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен никакой `JS` для изменения `checked` атрибута, когда клиент кликает на радио кнопку в `DOM` обновляется атрибут `checked` и форма отправит новое значение на сервер. Убедитесь сами:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgVNrB

Поменял значение на `Opera`, получил

```
browser: opera
```

Что касается

> Но в моем случае хотелось бы явно установить, чтобы в консоле(во вкладке elements с исходным кодом) были видны изменения в html коде.

Мне кажется ради этого не стоит городить костыли